# Error with caret, using "out-of-bag" re-sampling

Tags: r, random-forest, caret, out-of-sample

When I run this code (R 2.13.2, caret 4.98 on windows 7):

```
library(caret)
data(iris)
TrainData <- iris[,1:4]
TrainClasses <- iris[,5]
rfFit <- train(TrainData, TrainClasses,
                 method = "rf",
                 tuneLength = 3,
                 trControl = trainControl(method = "oob"))
```

I get the following error:

```
Fitting: mtry=2 
Fitting: mtry=3 
Fitting: mtry=4 
Aggregating results
Selecting tuning parameters
Fitting model on full training set
Error in structure(list(method = method, modelType = modelType, results = performance,  : 
  object 'resampledCM' not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

/edit: I updated to caret 4.99 [using R forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=200), and the problem goes away.  It seems to have been unique to caret 4.98 and R 2.13.2.

Comment: Which version of `caret` are you using? (It works for me with `caret` v. 5.01-001, R v. 2.13.2.)

Comment: @chl: I'm using caret 4.98 and R 2.13.2.  I guess I have to wait until the windows version of caret on CRAN is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using 4.98 and R.2.13.0 - and the code works for me as well.
It looks similar to what happens when I break Caret when I forget to remove my own custom functions (I no longer modify the default for this reason).  If you have checked:

trainControl()

and haven't found anything - that is my only suggestion.

I have broken Caret many, many times and have never seen that specific error.  I have seen it with "object 'XXXXX' not found"

With XXXX being in some function I made.

Comment: It works for me on R 2.12.1.  The problem seems to be specific to R 2.13.1 and 2.13.2.